# Getting an error "appear to have very similar superblocks". Ways to fix it?

Tags: debian, raid, disk, mdadm, lsblk

So something strange is with my partitions.

```
root@rescue ~ # mdadm -A --scan
mdadm: WARNING /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb appear to have very similar superblocks.
      If they are really different, please --zero the superblock on one
      If they are the same or overlap, please remove one from the
      DEVICE list in mdadm.conf.
root@rescue ~ # lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0     4G  1 loop
sda      8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0     1G  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0    64G  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0   200G  0 part
├─sda4   8:4    0     1M  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0   2.5T  0 part
sdb      8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0   2.7T  0 part
sdc      8:32   0 223.6G  0 disk
```

On raid check I'm getting an error like this. Is there any way to fix it without data loss?

P.S. 
Added new output

```
root@rescue ~ # fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: ST3000NM0033-9ZM
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A93A2325-8454-A346-8133-2ACDF59BE163

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 5860533134 5860531087  2.7T Linux RAID

root@rescue ~ # mdadm --examine /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 1ac1670b:7c95ed23:0028a58b:a51e25d4
  Creation Time : Mon Dec  2 20:14:13 2019
     Raid Level : raid0
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Mon Dec  2 20:14:13 2019
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : a194544e - correct
         Events : 1

     Chunk Size : 8K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1

   0     0       8        5        0      active sync   /dev/sda5
   1     1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1


root@rescue ~ # mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 1ac1670b:7c95ed23:0028a58b:a51e25d4
  Creation Time : Mon Dec  2 20:14:13 2019
     Raid Level : raid0
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Mon Dec  2 20:14:13 2019
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : a194544e - correct
         Events : 1

     Chunk Size : 8K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1

   0     0       8        5        0      active sync   /dev/sda5
   1     1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: mdadm --examine? fdisk -l?

Comment: Yeah, but how would be the proper way to use it? Don't get me wrong, just don't wanna mess something up, not quite good with RAID.

Comment: @frostschutz means that just the `lsblk` output is not enough to understand your actual RAID configuration. The outputs of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`, `mdadm --examine /dev/sdb` and `mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1` would help a lot in understanding the configuration. These commands will not change anything; they will just display the current configuration. Please edit the outputs of those commands into your original question.

Comment: @telcoM Ah, thank you! Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common problem with old mdadm 0.90 metadata. This metadata is located somewhere at the end of the device, but not in the very last sector but at a 64K-aligned offset:

> The superblock is 4K long and is written into a 64K aligned block that starts at least 64K and less than 128K from the end of the device (i.e. to get the address of the superblock round the size of the device down to a multiple of 64K and then subtract 64K).

Source: https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats#The_version-0.90_Superblock_Format

Unfortunately, for a whole disk device that is not multiple of 64K large, and has a partition extending to very near the end of disk (into the last partial 64K block), it means the superblock position for the last partition, and the superblock position for the whole drive, turns out to be completely identical.

The mdadm manpage also mentions this issue:

> ```
>            0, 0.90
>                  Use the original 0.90 format superblock.  This format
>                  limits arrays to 28 component devices and limits
>                  component devices of levels 1 and greater to 2 terabytes.
>                  It is also possible for there to be confusion about
>                  whether the superblock applies to a whole device or just
>                  the last partition, if that partition starts on a 64K
>                  boundary.
> ```

Indirectly it also suggests another workaround: just don't make the partition 64K-aligned; then the superblock on the partition won't be 64K-aligned to the disk, and as such, it couldn't be seen as superblock for the whole disk.

But in your case, your partition is MiB aligned which also makes it 64K aligned. The superblock position for the partition is `2048(start) + 5860531087(size) - 15(size%128) = 5860532992`, the superblock position for the disk is `5860533168(size) - 48(size%128) - 128 = 5860532992`.

In other words, **you don't have two superblocks here; it's one and the same.** If you `mdadm --zero-superblock` one as the message suggested, you end up losing both. So please, don't do that.

Adding a DEVICE line in mdadm.conf is an easy workaround for one system, but once you boot a Live CD or Initramfs that doesn't have your mdadm.conf, the problem just resurfaces.

---

This is one of several reasons why 0.90 metadata should be avoided. Use 1.x metadata instead.

`mdadm` allows converting from 0.90 to 1.0 metadata format, for example like this:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/mdX
mdadm --assemble /dev/mdX --update=metadata /dev/sdx1 /dev/sdy1
```

From the manpage:

> The metadata option only works on v0.90 metadata arrays and will
>   convert them to v1.0 metadata.  The array must not be dirty (i.e. it
>   must not need a sync) and it must not have a write- intent bitmap.

Using the default 1.2 metadata (located at the start instead of end) would be even better, but it would require all data to be shifted and can't be converted in-place.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for help! Just to clarify, i should do it like this
`mdadm --stop /dev/md0` and `mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 --update=metadata /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdb` In my case?

Comment: No, you have to assemble it correctly with the device names you're actually using. In your case this should be /dev/sda5 and /dev/sdb1. If sdb1 was wrong (if the partition table is not on your disk but on the raid device itself) only then would you use sdb instead of sdb1. But that's not your case (and not recommended in general).

Comment: Note there may also be other side effects from metadata conversion. If you are currently relying on RAID auto-assembly (what people used before initrd came about), that might no longer work afterwards. If your mdadm.conf is specifically looking for a 0.90 metadata device you might have to edit that too.

Comment: Yeah, i think i can run afterwards the `mdadm --examine --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` to fix it.

Comment: Also check your existing `mdadm.conf` file: if it lists `/dev/sdb` (instead or in addition to `/dev/sdb1`) on a `DEVICE` line, you should remove the reference to `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: @telcoM in mdadm.conf i can see only this `ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=1ac1670b:7c95ed23:0028a58b:a51e25d4
`

Comment: @Viktor that's fine

Comment: @frostschutz I'm getting something like this => http://prntscr.com/qebtt6

Comment: @Viktor does it still say 0.90 in --examine, also for sda5? "is busy" usually means it's already assembled, check /proc/mdstat